# What is actually happening when you omit .catch from JavaScript Promises?

Tags: javascript

The following two functions behave identically when called.

```
function func1() {
    return asyncFunc()
        .then(() => {
            // do something
        });
}

function func2() {
    return asyncFunc()
        .then(() => {
            // do something
        }).catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
}
```

I know that .catch() is merely syntactic sugar for `Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onRejected)` per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch). However, I'm confused as to what actually occurs behind the scenes when you omit .catch from a promise chain.

**What is actually going on behind the scenes when there is no .catch() in a promise chain? Is a `.catch((err) => { throw err;});` being "magically" appended somehow?**

Comment: @axiac yep, I get the part about how the exception flows to any upper levels but my question is more about how that happens. Like is a `.catch((err) => { throw err; });` magically appended to a promise chain that does not have a .catch() statement?

Comment: @axiac A rejected promise does not cause the script to terminate, since it's running asynchronously and there's no context to terminate. All it does is cause an error message to be logged, and no further `.then` to be executed.

Comment: @deceze the depends on the js environment. In future node version the process will be indeed terminated. But for a browser it is unlikely that they will do such a thing in future, neither for the tab and for sure not for the whole browser.

Comment: `.catch((err) => { throw err;});` is a no-op, it returns a promise that fulfills when the original fulfills and gets rejected when the original is rejected.

Comment: "*I'm confused as to what actually occurs behind the scenes when you omit .catch from a promise chain*" - well, nothing occurs, you just return the promise directly from `func1`.

Comment: Strange  that none of the answers in fact addressed the magic that you are asking, the 'then' functions you passed are pre-wrapped in a try/catch block even if .catch handler is not attached. That's why it doesn't throw (only squeals uncaught bla bla..) but can react in case a catch handler is present.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin So just to clarify. Are you saying that any code within 'then' of a promise is wrapped in a try-catch block?

Comment: yes, that's what I am saying.

Comment: That makes things so much clearer...

Comment: I just wrote a promise implementation to demonstrate that to you, then double checked with A++ implementations, turns out I was correct. Well there is no other way anyway, how else that behavior would be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.catch((err) => { throw err;})`  would not do anything, it would just re throw the error. So the Promise returned by `.catch` will be rejected with the error `err` again:

```js
Promise.reject(new Error('test'))
.catch(err => {
   console.error(err)
   throw err
})
.catch(err => {
   console.error(err)
})
```

`func1` would return a Promise that might be rejected by some event that happens in that chain. So the caller of the `func1` might want to handle that error, or if the the caller passes the received Promise further, and does not want to handle that error, then also the caller can omit the catch.

But the one *"owning"* the chain (the one who received it last and does not pass it to anyone else), is responsible to handle the rejection case.

```js
function func1() {
    return asyncFunc()
        .then(() => {
            // do something
        });
}

function callerA() {
   return func1()
}

function callerB() {
    // callerB does not return the promise retuirned by callerA, 
    // and does not pass it to any other function, so it has to handle
    // the rjection case
   callerA().catch(err => {
     
   })
}
```

On a rejection the js environment will check if there this error is catched anywhere in the chain. If that is not the case then a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` might be thrown:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Or in case of the browser the error is logged in the console.

How the js enviroment deals with unhandled rejections depends, nodejs currently emits this warning:

> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

And as it says will terminate the application in future versions.

For the browser it is unlikely that it will terminate the tab future. It most likely will always only log that error in the console, but you still should write your code as if the unhandled rejection would terminate the context.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are definitely functionally equivalent, there is no magic happening behind the scenes. The `Promise` handler callbacks are designed to automatically handle values that are thrown and apply them to the promise chain.

Consider the following example:

```
Promise.resolve("{") // broken JSON
    .then((json) => {
        return JSON.parse(json)  // Throws SyntaxError
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        throw err; // Throws the same SyntaxError
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err); // Logs the SyntaxError
    });
```

Most `Promise` implementations have a feature that logs the error when you have not attached an error handler to a promise that was rejected, some even allow you to register a custom event handler (e.g. [Chrome](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/promise-rejection-events/) and [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly)) when an unhandled rejection occurs. But not all runtimes are created equal, the Promise implementation in Edge, for instance, does not provide such feature for notifying users of unhandled rejections.

Comment: They most likely will add the logging also to Edge [github: Microsoft/ChakraCore
: Detect unhandled promise rejection #2530](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/2530)

Answer (score 0):

> **Q:** Is a .catch((err) => { throw err;}); being "magically" appended somehow?
>
> **A: NO, NOT AT ALL!**

The `.then` method itself returns a promise. And, if you call a `.catch` method on that returned promise the handler passed in the catch would get called if that promise got rejected. The handler would simply get ignored if the promise got resolved. Read more about error handling in JS promises [here](https://hackernoon.com/promises-and-error-handling-4a11af37cb0e).

And, as I already mentioned, the catch method doesn't magically get appended. Your code would just get ignore if the promise returned by `.then` method would get rejected because you didn't catch it. Run the following code for a better understanding:

```js
var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(reject, 100);
});

myPromise
 .then(() => console.log('hi')); // Prints nothing

myPromise
 .then(() => console.log('hi'))
 .catch(() => console.log('hello'));  // Prints hello
```

Comment: That does not really answer the question. The OP is wondering if a `catch` is auto append to handle the error in case when not `catch`has been appended in the code.